# R function returns only 1 output instead of list of outputs (with no error message)

Tags: r, function, vector, vectorization

I was not able to find a solution to this exact problem so would appreciate any and all help!

I am writing the following function:

```
SS_function_cl = function(MDE, variance, variance_endline, k, cluster_size, sig_t, power_t, binary_baseline, binary_endline){ 
  1 + 
((((sig_t + power_t)^2)* ((variance/cluster_size) + (variance_endline/cluster_size) + ((k^2)*(binary_baseline^2 +binary_endline^2))))/(binary_baseline^2 * binary_endline^2))
}
```

Which has each of the following inputs:

```
binary_baseline = .5
MDE_value = .25
binary_endline = .5 + .25
variance = binary_baseline*(1-binary_baseline)
variance_endline = binary_endline*(1-binary_endline)
ICC = .2
k = sqrt((ICC*((1-binary_baseline)/binary_baseline)))
top_y = 1
bottom_y = .05
MDE = seq(bottom_y, top_y, by=((top_y-bottom_y)*.05))
sig_t = qt(p = 1-(.05/2), df = 100000000)
power_t = qt(p = .8, df = 100000000) 

cluster_size = 20
N_clusters = SS_function_cl(MDE, variance, variance_endline, k, cluster_size, sig_t, power_t, binary_baseline, binary_endline)
sample_size = cluster_size * N_clusters
```

To create the following figure:

```
data <- data.frame(MDE,sample_size)
data %>% ggplot(aes(x=sample_size, y=MDE)) +
  geom_line(aes(color="E35925")) +
  geom_point(aes(color="E35925")) +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14), 
        text = element_text(family = "Century Gothic")) +
  labs(y= "MDE", x = "Sample Size") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=MDE_value, color = "#2FAA9F")
```

Which should look something like this:
[image]

The issue is that althought my MDE input shows up as a vector of numbers, my N_clusters output shows only one value. I'm not sure where this is coming from, because all of the other functions in my code are pretty similar and they all work. Could anyone help figure this out?

[image]

Thanks so much!

I tried returning a list and the lapply function but I'm relatively new to R and so I can't really figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the function you created (SS_function_cl) isn't using the MDE variable. All other inputs are single values so the return of a single value would be expected.

Comment: Wow, haha. To think I spent so much time and missed that. Thank you so much!